# Pyplot 3D scatter z axis issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there something wrong with the 3d plt.scatter(x,y,z) method?

Plots all z values at zero:

```
x = [1, 1]
y = [1, 1]
z = [-10, 10]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 18))
plt.axes(projection ="3d")
plt.scatter(x, y, z, color='k')

plt.show()
```

Working correctly:

```
x = [1, 1]
y = [1, 1]
z = [-10, 10]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 18))
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")
ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='k')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your above examples you used the two [matplotlib's interfaces](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/): pyplot vs object oriented.

If you'll look at the [source code of `pyplot.scatter`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L2775) you'll see that even if you are going to provide 3 arguments `plt.scatter(x, y, z, color='k')`, it is actually going to call the 2D version, with `x, y, s=z`, `s` being the marker size.

So, it appears that you have to use the object oriented approach to achieve your goals.